# Positional frequency counts for letters in cells in a csv file

Tags: php, python, design-patterns, csv, counter

I've been trying to use PHP / Python to figure out the most efficient way to parse the contents of a CSV file that has been uploaded to it through a web form. In short, it contains a series of strings that has already been split by letter and where the first integer indicates the number of occurrences for that particular string.

For instance:

```
2,f,o,o
6,h,e,l,l,o
7,a,i,r,p,l,a,n,e
```

I'm trying to figure out how to return the number of occurrences of each letter taking into account its position (first, last or anywhere in the middle) and total occurrences of the string.

Example:

```
First Position:
f: 2
h: 6
a: 7

Last Position:
o: 8
e: 7

Middle: 
Anything left over.
```

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far.  We don't like to do people's homework for them.

Comment: I guess `defaultdict(int)` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The guys are correct that you should attempt this, especially since it's not very hard, also if it is homework (is it?)
Here are enough hints:

- Define a base class *`Counter`* using *`collections.defaultdict`* to implement the *`collections.Counter`* just like [the new Counter in 3.1](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). It must have an update() method, you can overload that with a frequency argument, default to *`...,frequency=1)`*. - It will also need a *`most_common()`* method, you can directly use *`max(Counter.values())`*, no need to convert to list then sort. Then use a list comprehension to find the letter(s) with that max frequency. Beware to define how to handle the case with more than one letter having max freq.
- Declare three *`Counters firstLetter, middleLetters, lastLetter`*
- For each line:
- Convert line to list by splitting on ',' Unpack each line (helper fn, or just straight tuple unpacking in 3.x) into *`(freq,first,middle,last)`* where *`middle`* is itself a tuple. Or just use indexing: *`a[0],a[1],a[2:-2],a[-1]`*
- Sum letter counts using collections.Counter or defaultdict, and multiply all values by freq
- Find letter with max frequency either with *`most_common()`* or using comprehensions. Oh you didn't even need that.